# Test Recursive Python Function

Tags: python, testing, recursion, mocking

I have a recursive function that I'm looking to test, however I'm having difficulty limiting the recursive call during testing. For example, below is a simple example of a recursive function that calls a bool_function(n) to check if it should break the recursive loop.

```
def factorial(n):
  if bool_function(n):
      return 1
  else:
      return n * factorial(n-1)
```

What would be the best way to test or mock bool_function(n) so that it is true for the first iteration and false for any call after?

Comment: Are you using unittest?

Comment: Unless `bool_function` has side effects why bother. Can't you just test with `n` that you know hits a `True`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always implement a class to encapsulate the state and give you more flexibility, here's a sketch:

```
>>> class MockBoolCheck:
...     def __init__(self, fail_after=0):
...         self.count = 0
...         self.fail_after = fail_after
...     def __call__(self, n):
...         called = self.count
...         self.count += 1
...         return called <= self.fail_after
...
>>> bool_function = MockBoolCheck()
>>> bool_function(42)
True
>>> bool_function(42)
False
>>> bool_function(42)
False
>>> bool_function(42)
False
>>> bool_function(42)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

If, beside other suggested solutions, you really want to mock it, and want to do it yourself (without the mocking libraries) by just replacing the mocked function.

```
# Your code (or module):

def bool_function(n):
    print('REAL bool-function {}'.format(n))
    return n <= 0

def factorial(n):
    print('FACT {}'.format(n))
    if bool_function(n):
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

# Mocking code (or module):

def mock_function(n):
    print('MOCK bool-function {}'.format(n))
    global bool_function
    bool_function = bool_func_orig  # restore on the first use
    return False
bool_func_orig = bool_function
bool_function = mock_function  # mock it

# Go run it!
factorial(10)
```

If these are two separate modules, then instead of `global bool_function` & `bool_function=...` just use the `somemodule.bool_function=...`.

If you want to use the mocking library, then it depends on which library you use. If that is `unittest.mock`, then you should play with `side_effect=...` & `wraps=...` (see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock)). The same approach: mock it, and un-mock it from inside the side effect on the first use.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try not to leave debug code around unless I expect to use it regularly, but you could just include a default argument for the sake of debugging to force the execution to follow a particular path.

```
def factorial(n, debug=False):
  if bool_function(n) or debug:
      return 1
  else:
      return n * factorial(n-1)
```

This naturally implies that you're also externally testing `bool_function()`

Comment: I strongly recommend not to pass any `debug` arguments. If function cannot be tested - it means that design is bad, adding one more workaround does not guarantee that function itself works.

Comment: @TarasMatsyk perhaps this is the result of an over-simplified example, but I believe the greater simplicity and readability outweighs the modularity in this case. Particularly if the predicate will otherwise only ever be a single function, this approach both simplifies the reading of the code as well as the execution.

Comment: agree from this perspective

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the function as an argument. If function is None you can apply some default behavior if that is desired.

This is a common approach used in `queries to iterables` (e.g. Django queries or Peewee queries) in most of languages.

A function that returns boolean is usually called a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic))

```
def factorial(n, predicate=None):
  if not predicate:
     predicate = lambda x: x > 2

  if predicate(n):
      return 1
  else:
      return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For python > 3.6

```
import mock   
class RecursividadeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_recursive(self):
        with mock.patch('path.factorial') as mock_fact:
            factorial(3)
            self.assertTrue(mock_fact.called)
            self.assertGreaterEqual(mock_fact.call_count, 2)

    def test_recursive_2(self):
    with mock.patch('incolumepy.sequences.fibonacci.fibonacci') as mock_fib:
        for i in range(1, 5, -1):
            expected = i - 1
            fibonacci(i)
            self.assertTrue(mock_fib.called)
            self.assertEqual(mock_fib.call_count, expected)
```